# How to calculate weighted Hedges' g effect size in meta-analysis when some effect sizes share a control group?

Tags: spss, meta-analysis, effect-size

I am trying to do a meta-analysis using Hedges' G as the effect size.

#### Questions

1. Some of the studies have different groups but the same control group. How does this change the computation and pooling of effect sizes?
2. How do I calculate a weighted effect size for each study so that I can perform moderator effect analysis using SPSS?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but Larry Hedges has coauthored books on meta-analysis and it would seem those books would be good places to look to find your answers.  Here are the links: 1. [Olkin and Hedges](http://www.amazon.com/Statistical-Methods-Meta-Analysis-Larry-Hedges/dp/0123363802/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1348050682&sr=1-3&keywords=meta+analysis+Hedges)  2. [Borenstein, Hedges et al.](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Meta-Analysis-Statistics-Practice-Borenstein/dp/0470057246/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1348050800&sr=1-1&keywords=meta+analysis+Hedges)

Comment: 3. [Handbook, co-edited by Hedges](http://www.amazon.com/Handbook-Research-Synthesis-Meta-Analysis/dp/0871541637/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1348050925&sr=1-2&keywords=meta+analysis+Hedges)

Comment: Regarding question 1: Some issues are discussed in [The Degree of Dependence between Multiple-Treatment Effect Sizes](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00273171003680104) by Kim/Becker (2010).

Answer (score 3):

With regards to common control groups, you may want to check out [16.5.4 of the Cochrane Handbook](http://www.mrc-bsu.cam.ac.uk/cochrane/handbook/chapter_16/16_5_4_how_to_include_multiple_groups_from_one_study.htm). To quote a subset of this page:

> Approaches to overcoming a unit-of-analysis error for a study that
>   could contribute multiple, correlated, comparisons include the
>   following.
>
> - Combine groups to create a single pair-wise comparison
>     (recommended).
> - Select one pair of interventions and exclude the
>     others.
> - Split the ‘shared’ group into two or more groups with smaller
>     sample size, and include two or more (reasonably independent)
>     comparisons.
> - Include two or more correlated comparisons and account
>     for the correlation.
> - Undertake a multiple-treatments meta-analysis
>     (see Section 16.6).
>
> The recommended method in most situations is to
>   combine all relevant experimental intervention groups of the study
>   into a single group, and to combine all relevant control intervention
>   groups into a single control group. As an example, suppose that a
>   meta-analysis of ‘acupuncture versus no acupuncture’ would consider
>   studies of either ‘acupuncture versus sham acupuncture’ or studies of
>   ‘acupuncture versus no intervention’ to be eligible for inclusion.
>   Then a study comparing ‘acupuncture versus sham acupuncture versus no
>   intervention’ would be included in the meta-analysis by combining the
>   participants in the ‘sham acupuncture’ group with participants in the
>   ‘no intervention’ group. This combined control group would be compared
>   with the ‘acupuncture’ group in the usual way. For dichotomous
>   outcomes, both the sample sizes and the numbers of people with events
>   can be summed across groups. For continuous outcomes, means and
>   standard deviations can be combined using methods described in Chapter
>   7 (Section 7.7.3.8).

With regards to pooling effect sizes for performing moderator meta analysis. There is a list of [SPSS resources here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5220/how-to-do-meta-regression-analysis-with-spss). You might want to get a book like *Introduction to Meta-Analysis* to provide an overview of some of the many issues and calculations involved.

#### References

- Borenstein, M., Hedges, L.V., Higgins, J.P.T. & Rothstein, H.R. (2011). Introduction to meta-analysis. John Wiley \& Sons